# Select DataFrame rows of a specific day

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with a date_time column. The date_time column contains a date and time. I also managed to convert the column to a datetime object.

I want to create a new DataFrame containing all the rows of a specific DAY.

I managed to do it when I set the date column as the index and used the "loc" method.

Is there a way to do it even if the date column is not set as the index? I only found a method which returns the rows between two days.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: What about: df = df_with_date[df_with_date.dateColumn == date]?

Comment: `df2 = df1.loc[df1.datecol==prefereddate]`

Comment: @Sandertjuhh I forgot to mention that the date column is a datetime object with a date as well as time. I tried this and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [groupby()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) function. Let's say your dataframe is `df`,

```
df_group = df.groupby('Date') # assuming the column containing dates is called Date.
```

Now you can access rows of any date by passing the date in the get_group function,

```
df_group.get_group('date_here')
```

Comment: unfortunately, when I type a date into 'date_here', it returns a key error. I think this is due to the fact that the date column contains a date as well as a time

Comment: @Roy_Oliver Can you add your dataframe in the question and what key you are using , so that I can tell you the specific command.